# FindFit with a Sin function

Tags: fitting, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the fit of Sin-shaped weather data that is provided by Wolfram. My code is as follows:

```
plot = DateListPlot[
  WeatherData["Toronto", 
   "MeanTemperature", {{2016, 1, 1}, {2019, 12, 31}, "Day"}, 
   Joined -> True]]
data = Cases[plot, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i++, {
  data[[i]][[1]] = i;
  }]
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
FindFit[data, a*Sin[b*x + c] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

The original data looks like this:

[image: OG data]

but what I get when I graph my Fitted data using `Plot[a*Sin[b*x + c] + d /. %, {x, 1, 1400}]` is:

[image: output]

How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92523/12558) which discusses difficultes of fitting a sine wave.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This question has nothing to do with networks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `NonlinearModellFit` ( `Method->"NMinimize"` needs no starting values) instead:

```
mod = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin[b*x + c] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x,Method -> "NMinimize"]
Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[mod[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image]

`Fit[ …,Method -> "NMinimize"]` works too!

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Ulrich Neumann is the right way to do it. But for fun, here is a method using Fourier series approximation.

The idea is to fit the model on the Fourier series, and let the `NonlinearModelFit` determine the coefficients $a_n,b_n$. The period is taken as one year, or 364 days.

```
plot = DateListPlot[
  WeatherData["Toronto", "MeanTemperature", {{2016, 1, 1}, {2019, 12, 31}, "Day"}, 
   Joined -> True]]
data = Cases[plot, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity];

ClearAll[a, n, b, d];
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 1]] = Range[Length@data];
data2[[All, 2]] = LowpassFilter[data2[[All, 2]], .1];

(*set up the Fourier series approximation*)
expr = d + Sum[(a[n] Cos[2 n Pi/364 x] + b[n] Sin[2 n Pi/364 x]), {n, 1, 150}];

(*this will be the fitted formula. it has 301 terms*)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data2, expr, Flatten[{d, Array[a, 150], Array[b, 150]}], x] ;

Show[{Plot[Normal[fit], {x, 0, Length@data}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]