# NonlinearModelFit gives weird result

Tags: fitting

I was trying to fit some data similar to sine, but always get weird results. So I searched and found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225425/4742).

Surprisingly, I can not reproduce the result. With below code

```
plot = DateListPlot[
   WeatherData["Toronto", 
    "MeanTemperature", {{2016, 1, 1}, {2019, 12, 31}, "Day"}, 
    Joined -> True]];
data = Cases[plot, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity];
mod = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin[b*x + c] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x, 
   Method -> "NMinimize"];
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[mod[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

What I got is

[image]

My Mathematica version is 12.2.0.0. What is wrong?

Comment: Look at the x-scale in the original post and your x-scale. ``NonlinearModelFit`` needs some reasonable starting values for the parameters, otherwise it sets them to 1. Instead of ``{a, b, c, d}`` write ``{a, {b, 10^-11}, c, d}``.

Comment: @Domen Thank you for reply. But I got "NMinimize::parchange: Inappropriate parameter: InitialPoints -> {1,1/100000000000,1,1}, changed to Automatic."

Comment: In this case drop the `Method -> "NMinimize"` option and use reasonable guesses for the parameters.  `a`: `(Quantile[data[[All, 2]], 0.95] - Quantile[data[[All, 2]], 0.05])/2`.  `b`: `(2 \[Pi] 4)/Differences[MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]]`. `d`: `Mean[data[[All, 2]]]`.  Or `{{a, 16}, {b, 2 10^-7}, c, {d, 10}}`.  Because `a`, `c`, and `d` are on wildly different scales than  `b`, you'll just have to guess well to get convergence.

Comment: If one knew enough to roughly equalize the values of the parameters with `a*Sin[10^(-7) b*x + c] + d`, then using no initial values and `Method -> "NMinimize"` would work.

Comment: @JimB Thank you so much. That indeed works. But it seems that the original post has no such delicate parameter tuning to get correct result.

Comment: As @domen mentioned earlier take a look at the horizontal axis of that original post.  That’s the explanation for the difference.

Comment: One more comment:  this issue doesn't just pertain to *Mathematica* regression functions.  The same thing happens with R, SAS, etc.  Especially if the proposed model is based on theoretical considerations, then one should attempt to figure out reasonable starting values and modify the appearance of the model to have parameters of similar orders of magnitude to assist with the stability of the iterative procedures.

Comment: @JimB Thank you so much! I understand :)