# My sinusoidal fit requires an unused extra constant to work

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, trigonometry

I am trying to fit a sinusoidal curve onto the following data:

```
{{1., 7.01355*10^6}, {2., 1.30596*10^7}, {3., 1.63411*10^7}, {4., 
  1.47326*10^7}, {5., 8.76634*10^6}, {6., 
  316088.}, {7., -7.85484*10^6}, {8., -1.4528*10^7}, {9., \
-1.71655*10^7}, {10., -1.68664*10^7}, {11., -1.18768*10^7}, {12., \
-5.55405*10^6}}
```

Following the advice from [this previous StackExchange post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225422/findfit-with-a-sin-function), I ran the following code:

```
Fit1 = 
 NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin[b*x] + d, {a, b, c, d},
   x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

This gives the solid curve below with an excellent fit. However, I noticed that I'd incorrectly included the extra fitting term "c" in my code. (This was included in the original code as `a*Sin[b*x+c]`, however the experimental sinusoidal behaviour should always have c = 0).

As "c" isn't included in the function I am fitting, I removed it, but then observed an entirely different fit (the dashed line).

```
Fit2 = 
 NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin[b*x] + d, {a, b, d}, x,
   Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

[image: Plot showing the two fits - good fit with bad code solid, and bad fit with good code dashed]

Could anybody advise why I am seeing such different results? Is it due to my use of NMinimize, which I will admit I don't properly understand?

Comment: I can not reproduce, I got the same result with `c` or without on version 13.0.1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Both methods [give the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPILM.png). It might be that you have some symbols defined which interfere. Can you please try the code in a fresh kernel? Also, please include your version of Mathematica in the question.

Comment: With v14.0.0 on a Mac, `d` is the same but the signs on `a` and `b` are reversed between the fits., i.e., graphically they are the same.

Comment: A very similar question was asked 4 days ago "Problem related to fitting a damped sine function". In most cases, it is required to provide starting values for the parameters: NonlinearModelFit[data,  a*Sin[b*x] + d, {{a, 1.6 10^7}, {b, 0.5}, {d, 0}}, x] works even with the default method. It seems that NMinimize is less sensitive to the initial parameter guesses, and may be the algorithms to find these guesses changed with Mathematica versions.

Comment: Thanks everybody. @Domen, my version is 13.2.1.0. Using a fresh kernel has addressed the issue, thank you!