# Prony series with a large number of terms

Tags: fitting

A Prony series is similar to a Fourier series but can have fewer terms. It takes the form

$\sum_{i=1}^{M} A_i e^{\sigma _i t} \cos \left(\omega _i t+\phi _i\right)$

Note that unlike Fourier series there is a decay term and further, the frequency does not have to be equally spaced increments. Details may be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method).

The problem I am addressing here is how to find the terms of this series when approximating a function.

Building on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94713/12558) answer from Daniel Lichtblau I first generated some data as follows:

```
ClearAll[amp, freq]
amp = Interpolation[{{0, 9.870000000000001`}, {0.1795`, 
     6.69`}, {0.41150000000000003`, 3.04`}, {0.6385000000000001`, 
     0.96`}, {1, 0.25`}}];
freq = Interpolation[{{0, 79.2`}, {0.2545`, 
     99.80000000000001`}, {0.4985`, 109.2`}, {0.7395`, 
     113.60000000000001`}, {1, 115.60000000000001`}}];
sr = 1500; data = 
 Table[{t, amp[t] Cos[2 π freq[t] t]}, {t, 0, 1 - 1/sr, 1/sr}];
ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note this is not an exponential decay. If it was exponential then only two terms in the Prony series would be needed. Here we need many more.

```
 th = data[[All, 2]];
tt = data[[All, 1]];
nn = Length@data;
nc = 300; (* number of terms *)
mat = Most[Partition[th, nc, 1]];
rhs = Drop[th, nc];
soln = PseudoInverse[mat].rhs;
roots = xx /. NSolve[xx^nc - soln.xx^Range[0, nc - 1] == 0, xx];
e = roots^(t sr);
mat2 = Table[e, {t, tt}];
coeffs = LeastSquares[mat2, th];
eqn = coeffs.e;
```

This fit has 300 terms. It throws out an error that precision may be lost. So that need fixing. The data can be regenerated as follows. I plot the fit and the original data and the difference between the two.

```
fit = Table[eqn, {t, tt}];
ListLinePlot[{data, Transpose[{tt, fit}]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{tt, data[[All, 2]] - fit}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Data and fit]
[image: error]

This is not bad but we need more terms. Here I try with 500 terms and also set the precision to avoid the error in the first try.

```
sp = 50; (* precision *)
th = data[[All, 2]];
tt = SetPrecision[data[[All, 1]], sp];
nn = Length@data;
nc = 500; (* number of terms *)
mat = Most[Partition[th, nc, 1]];
rhs = Drop[th, nc];
soln = PseudoInverse[mat].rhs;
roots = xx /. NSolve[xx^nc - soln.xx^Range[0, nc - 1] == 0, xx];
e = SetPrecision[roots^(t sr), sp];
mat2 = Table[e, {t, tt}];
coeffs = LeastSquares[mat2, th];
eqn = coeffs.e;
```

Now to plot the fit and look at the error

```
fit = Table[eqn, {t, tt}];
err = Transpose[{tt, th - fit}];
ListLinePlot[{data, Transpose[{tt, fit}]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[err, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All
```

]

[image: Second attempt at fitting]

[image: error in second fit]

This is getting better with an order of magnitude smaller error. However, I am struggling with the loss of precision and need more terms. Can this fitting method using Prony series be made better?  Is more precision the only solution?

Comment: The amplitudes begin to grow  for `t>0.9`, is this intended?

Comment: The Prony series should be able to cope with this. Certainly, a Fourier series can.  I think Prony can. Whereas Fourier would require as many points in the spectrum as time domain points Prony will use fewer depending on the accuracy required.

Comment: Is it known that a Prony series can give a close fit here? If so, my guess is that NSolve will be less than stellar for the case where many terms are required (high degree polynomial, that is).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Don't be so pessimistic! I have just posted an answer for my Prony series approach that successfully calculates the roots of a polynomial of order 1499. Don't know how to prove that you can use a Prony series to approximate "any" function but I would guess it should be the same as a Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

It might be beneficial to use `NonlinearModelFit`.  Here are the results when just 15 terms are estimated (which is equivalent to 60 parameters).

```
m = 15;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Sum[a[i] Exp[σ[i] t] Cos[ω[i] t + ϕ[i]], {i, m}],
   Flatten[Table[{a[i], σ[i], ω[i], ϕ[i]}, {i, m}]], t, MaxIterations -> 10000];
Show[Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True], PlotLabel -> "Data and fit"]
```

[image: Data and fit]

```
ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"], PlotLabel -> "Residuals vs t"]
```

[image: Residuals vs t]

Comment: Interesting idea to let NonlinearModalFit find the terms. How did you find the number of terms that are a good fit? Thanks

Comment: I would use the term "natural choice" rather than "interesting idea".  Why would you want to roll your own regression function when `NonlinearModelFit` has a lot of built-in checks to get a solution?  As far as choosing a value for `m`, I just tried a few values to get the residuals below 0.02 to show as an example.  In practice I would use $AIC_c$ to decide on a value of `m`.

Comment: Thanks. Natural choice does not always apply with NonlinearModalFit.  See here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92523/12558) for an example that is unnatural! What does AICc mean! I don't know the acronym?

Comment: Among most disciplines using $AIC$ and $AIC_c$ for the last 20 years has taken on a religious fervor so I would imagine you haven't had a class in regression for a while. You need to get out more.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc

Answer (score 0):

I have been working at this problem and have used `RecurrenceTable` to avoid the precision issues. It seems to work. The other concern is calculating the roots of a very large polynomial. In the example below I calculate the roots of a polynomial of order 1499. It seems to work!

Here is a module I have constructed for approximating a time history of the form data = { {t1, y1}, {t2, y2}...}

```
ClearAll[myProny];
myProny::usage = 
  "myProny[data,nc] Calculates a Prony series approximation to the \
time history data. nc is the number of coefficients in the \
approximation.
  Output is {regenerated time history, Prony roots, mean square \
error}";
myProny[data_, nc_] := 
 Module[{th, tt, nn, mat, rhs, soln, roots, mat2, coeffs, res, err, 
   xx, y, n},
  th = data[[All, 2]];
  tt = data[[All, 1]];
  nn = Length@data;
  mat = Most[Partition[th, nc, 1]];
  rhs = Drop[th, nc];
  soln = PseudoInverse[mat].rhs;
  roots = xx /. NSolve[xx^nc - soln.xx^Range[0, nc - 1] == 0, xx];
  mat2 = Transpose[RecurrenceTable[
       {y[n] == #  y[n - 1], y[1] == 1},
       y,   {n, nn}] & /@ roots
    ];
  coeffs = LeastSquares[mat2, th];
  res = mat2.coeffs;
  err = res - th;
  {Transpose[{tt, res}], coeffs, err.err}
  ]
```

Starting again with the example.

```
ClearAll[amp, freq]
amp = Interpolation[{{0, 9.870000000000001`}, {0.1795`, 
     6.69`}, {0.41150000000000003`, 3.04`}, {0.6385000000000001`, 
     0.96`}, {1, 0.25`}}];
freq = Interpolation[{{0, 79.2`}, {0.2545`, 
     99.80000000000001`}, {0.4985`, 109.2`}, {0.7395`, 
     113.60000000000001`}, {1, 115.60000000000001`}}];
sr = 1500; data = 
 Table[{t, amp[t] Cos[2 \[Pi] freq[t] t]}, {t, 0, 1 - 1/sr, 1/sr}];
ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To start we try 500 coefficients. The output is the regenerated time history using the Prony series and the difference (error) in this approximation.

```
{res, coeffs, err} = myProny[data, 500];
ListLinePlot[res, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], res[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we try for the ultimate approximation. There are 1500 points in the time history and we ask for 1499 coefficients. The output is again the regenerated time history and the error.

```
{res, coeffs, err} = myProny[data, 1499];
ListLinePlot[res, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], res[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

The error appears to be numerical noise. So one can calculate the roots of a polynomial of order 1499!

Next  I calculate the relative error as a function of number of coefficients. The error is the mean square error divided by the total mean square value in the time history. The number of coefficients is divided by the number of points in the time history. It took 33 seconds to calculate 13 data points. Things are looking good when the number of coefficients in the Prony series is about 20%  of the total number of points in the time history.

```
Timing[all = 
   Table[{nc, 
     myProny[data, nc][[3]]}, {nc, {10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 
      550, 600, 700, 800, 1000, 1499}}];]
ms = data[[All, 2]].data[[All, 2]];
ListPlot[{#[[1]]/Length@data, #[[2]]/ms} & /@ all, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(Number\)\(\\\ \)\(of\)\(\\\ \)\
\(Coefficients\)\(\\\ \)\), \(Number\\\ of\\\ points\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(Mean\\\ Square\\\ Error\), \(Mean\\\ Square\\\
\ of\\\ Signal\)]\)"},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm not understanding the claim of success.  You end up getting estimates of 1499 coefficients from 1500 data points.  Isn't this analogous to fitting a 3rd order polynomial with 4 points?  How is that better than just having the 1500 data points?

Comment: @JimB Yes you are correct. In this case, to get this level of accuracy, we needed all the points. However, if we wanted less accuracy we could have used fewer coefficients. I deliberately constructed a difficult case. If the data had contained a mixture of decaying (possibly complex) exponentials then these would have been extracted explicitly.  The ability to represent the data as decaying exponentials is useful in my applications.

Comment: Seems like wishful thinking to me.  Have you considered any measures of precision for the coefficients?  You almost certainly will have high correlations among the coefficients (and by "high" I mean values close to +1 or -1).