# finding Frequency of Sinewave data using Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

## CONTEXT

I read 5 different related posts but I do not understand how to interpret mathematica's output for my situation.

```
data=(Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*Flatten@*(ImageData[#1, "Byte"] &)@*
   Import)["http://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/10/16/5803c2e35b8ac.png"]
```

> I have 300 measurements (taken every 1 second);
>
> I am told that the data is in the form $$y = A \sin{2\pi f t}$$
>
> I want to find the frequency $f$ using a fourier transform

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

#### plotting the data it seems (using my fallible human perception) that the period is not far of 18 seconds

```
Show[
     ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"s"}], 
     Plot[.03 Sin[2 \[Pi] (1/18) t] + Mean[data], {t, 0, 300},    
          PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed]
     ]
]
```

[image]

### note this code could be incorrect perhaps I need to include FourierParameters

```
powerSpectrum = Abs[Fourier[data[[All, 2]]]]^2;
ListLinePlot[powerSpectrum[[1 ;; 100]], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {All, {0, .012}}]
```

## QUESTION

Ignoring the outliers on the extreme left it appears that the highest  spike is near x = 18

How does one convert this into a frequency (number of oscillations in 1 second)?

Given that my sample length is 300 seconds?

[image]

Comment: You might synthesize some data where you know the frequency and you have less noise and see if your code gives the answer you expect. You might read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function on how to window your data and perhaps get better results.

Comment: thankyou will try to do that now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at my post on using Fourier [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) you will see that the frequency axis has an increment of the sample rate divided by the number of points and goes from zero to one less than the sample rate.

I also note that your data has a large mean value. It is worth removing this as it dominates the first point of the fourier transform. You tell us that the sample rate is 1 sample per second.

```
a = data[[All, 2]];
b = a - Mean[a];
sr = 1;  (* sample rate*)
nn = Length@data;
ff = Table[(n - 1) sr/nn, {n, nn}] // N;
ft = Fourier[b, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{ff, Abs[ft]}][[1 ;; 40]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a peak at point 18 corresponding to a frequency of 0.056666 Hz or a period of 17.6 sec.  However, the data is very noisy and nothing like a sine wave. I would recommend trying to get better data. Trying to estimate an exact sine wave from Fourier is difficult even if the data is good. Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42783/12558) for an extensive discussion on this topic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a side note, you can use `Periodogram` instead of the `Fourier` + `ListLinePlot` combination.

Comment: or this? `ListLinePlot[PeriodogramArray[b], PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 0.015}}]`

Comment: The sample rate is 1 not 300 (*"I have 300 measurements (taken every 1 second*)"

Comment: @SimonWoods  I took your quoted comment to mean that there is 300 measurements in one second. If we take it as 1 per second then that is a very different position. The suggested 18 Hz is then horribly aliased.  However your interpretation is supported by the abscissa of the data which increment by 1 for each point. We need to ask the question from the poster.

Comment: The OP mentioned a **period** of 18s, not a frequency of 18Hz.

Comment: @SimonWoods You have clearly read this properly and I have been sloppy in my interpretation. I will edit the post. Thanks