# Wrong frequency in Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a file, filled with data like this:
[image]

As you can see the approximate frequency is about $5/1000 = 0.005$, then angular frequency is about $2 \pi \times 0.005 \approx 0.03$.

Then I use discrete Fourier to obtain this frequency

```
 num = 3000;
 time = 30;
 ListPlot[(Sqrt[2 Pi]/Sqrt[num]) Abs[Fourier[list]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0, 5}} , DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi/0.01}]
```

(here I used $0.01$ which is $time/num$)

but the result is the following:

[image]

And the plot is going down with no peaks anymore (except mirror reflection on the right side).

So, what's wrong?

EDIT: If I delete PlotRange, the maximum of frequency lies to the left from the value 100. So I correct your PlotRange and then I get, for example, that maximum of frequency lies to the left from 50 and so on. Finally I'll finish with my picture and the maximum of frequency will be 0.

EDIT: Okay, I subtracted the average value from the list:

```
ListPlot[(Sqrt[2 Pi]/Sqrt[number]) Abs[Fourier[list - Mean[list]]], 
Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 0.01}}, 
DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi/0.01}]
```

Now there are two peaks, but where is frequency $\approx 0.03$?
[image]

Comment: Please share the data. You can look [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397) for ideas on how to share the data. You should also read [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44237/10397) and answers. The `Fourier` function does not scale the x axis.

Comment: I added some edits to my question.

Comment: A useful list of properties for Fourier including the correct selection of a frequency axis is given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in your use of `PlotRange`. Given a one-dimensional list as input `Fourier` returns a one-dimensional list as output. This list is considered a set of y-values only if plotted by `ListPlot`, which takes the x-values to be the consecutive integers 1, 2, 3 ...

With your plot range specification of {0, 0.07} for the x-range you create a problem. You could use `All` or `Automatic` instead. Or just remove `PlotRange`. You'll get something like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This all is assuming you have sampled your functions with fixed spacing.

**Update**

If you're interested in the location of the maximum frequency you have to account for the (documented) fact that the DC term is located in the first element of the output list. You can either throw this away in your plot (starting at position 2) or by subtracting the average value from the list:

```
ListPlot[(Sqrt[2 Pi]/Sqrt[num]) Abs[Fourier[list - Mean[list]]], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi/0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[(Sqrt[2 Pi]/Sqrt[num]) Abs[Fourier[list]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{2, All}, {0, 40}}, DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi/0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, I know. I have this plot. But the maximum of frequency lies to the left from the value 100. So you correct your PlotRange and you get, for example, that maximum of frequency lies to the left from 50 and so on. Finally you'll finish with my picture and the maximum of frequency will be 0.

Comment: @newt See update

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries Sorry, I think to estimate frequency value I should take number of oscillations per time, not per number of samples. Then I got right result.

Comment: @It all depends how you define frequency. There are many different versions around.

Answer (score 1):

If I estimate your data you have a time increment of 0.01 and a frequency of about 0.5 Hz. Thus

```
dt = 0.01;
f0 = 0.5;
data = N@Table[
    1000 + 10 Sin[2 \[Pi] f0 (n - 1) dt] + RandomReal[{-3, 3}],
```

{n,3000}];
    ListLinePlot[data]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we take the Fourier transform and also generate a frequency axis. Plotting on a log scale and also plotting with the low frequency (mean value) dropped gives the following plots.

```
ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
ff = N@Table[(n - 1)/(dt Length[ft]), {n, Length[ft]}];
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{ff, Abs[ft]}][[1 ;; 20]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency/Hz", "Modulus"}, 
 Joined -> True]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{ff, Abs[ft]}][[10 ;; 50]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency/Hz", "Modulus"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a clear peak at 0.5 Hz. More details on working with Fourier may be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558).
Hope that helps.