# How do I extract peak frequencies?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, peak-detection

Suppose I have large text file filled with numerical data. Then I do `Fourier` operation with this file and plot the result:

```
dataf = Import["filename.txt", {"Data", {All}, {2}}]; 
numbert = 800/0.05;
T = 800;
fourier = Sqrt[2 Pi]/Sqrt[numbert]* Abs[Fourier[dataf]];

ListPlot[fourier, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, 
  DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi numbert/T}]
```

[image]

How can I obtain numerical values of frequencies detected by `ListPlot`?
I tried `FindPeaks`, but it gets me big amount of data I can't work with.

I searched for examples, but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44237/10397). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Difficult to say much without the actual data. The link by @rhermans is promising though.

Comment: Try to increase the second parameter in `FindPeaks` (a smooth scale) or specify minimum peak height by the fourth parameter.

Comment: Some judicious use of the [`FourierParameters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierParameters.html) option would clean up some of the constants in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would try with the Select function. If your data is a list of pairs (freq,amp) then the code you would need would be something like:

```
Select[data,#[[2]]>xx&]
```

Where data is the list of pairs and xx is the threshold value. Since the spectrum would have a finite number of peaks as would be clear by looking into the plot, you can choose the xx value appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data and the output of `FindPeaks`, it is hard to say why the function does not work (it worked for me), but I wrote this simple function that will return the positions of peaks in an array:

```
peaks = Flatten[Position[Differences[Differences[array]], -2]] + 1
```

Given:

```
array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1};
```

peaks will return:

> `{5, 12}`

Incidentally, `FindPeaks` returns:

> `{{5, 4}, {12, 7}}`

which is in the following notation: {`position, value}`.

I hope this helps!